# Solution for system of equations returns empty set

Tags: python, sympy

I have a system of five equations with five unknowns. The returned solution is an EmptySet(). Solving only for two variables, e.g. Ta2, Tb2 returns the correct solution, but only as parametric form {(0.0400930157966482*Va2*pk, 0.0240558094779889*Vb2*pk)} of the other 3 variables. Is there a way to return numeric values of all five unknowns?

Solving the system of equations in a spreadsheet gives following results: pk = 246.274, Ta2 = 223.752,Tb2 = 280.451,Vb2 = 47.339,Va2 = 22.661. Substituting these into sympy output 0.0400930157966482*Va2*pk for Ta2 gives 223.752 as expected.

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve

Va, Ta, na = symbols('Va Ta na')
Vb, Tb, nb = symbols('Vb Tb nb')
pa, pb = symbols('pa pb')
R = symbols('R')
Ta2 , Tb2 = symbols('Ta2 Tb2')
Va2 , Vb2 = symbols('Va2 Vb2')
pk = symbols('pk')

R = 8.314

Va = 30.
Vb = 40.

Ta = 200.
Tb = 300.

na = 3.
nb = 5.

pa = na*R*Ta/Va
pb = nb*R*Tb/Vb

SumV = Va + Vb


eq1 = pa**5 * Va**7 - pk**5 * Va2**7
eq2 = pb**5 * Vb**7 - pk**5 * Vb2**7
eq3 = pk * Va2 - na * R * Ta2
eq4 = pk * Vb2 - nb * R * Tb2
eq5 = Va2 + Vb2 - SumV

system = [eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5]
solvefor = [Ta2, Tb2, pk, Va2, Vb2]

res = nonlinsolve(system, solvefor)
res
```

Comment: Are you sure this is solvable? A system of 5 uncorrelated equations with 5 variables has either, 0 or 1 solution. You might have found one with 0 solution

Comment: Solving in an Excel spreadsheet gives following results: pk = 246.274
Ta2 = 223.752,Tb2=280.451,Vb2 = 47.339,Va2= 22.661.

Comment: thanks, you should update your question by specifying a solution exists :) I ll have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to solve for the linear symbols so do that first:

```
>>> from sympy import solve, nsolve
>>> solve(system[-3:],Va2,Vb2,Ta2,dict=True)
[{Va2: 0.01*(-4157.0*Tb2 + 7000.0*pk)/pk, Vb2: 41.57*Tb2/pk, Ta2: -1.66666666666667*Tb2 + 2.80651110576538*pk}]
>>> s3=_[0]
```

Substitute that into the 2nd equation

```
>>> system[1].subs(s3)
-214516237736.33*Tb2**7/pk**2 + 4.82643407848195e+23
```

And solve for `pk**2`

```
>>> solve(_,pk**2)
[4.44461136831276e-13*Tb2**7]
```

Update the solution so far using the square-root (which should be ok if values are positive)

```
>>> s3.update({pk:sqrt(_[0])})
```

Subsitute this into the first equation and solve with bisection in the range of interest. The function is very flat in the region of interest so for rough estimation we leave verify off:

```
>>> system[0].subs(s3)
2.78002602920561e+21 - 4.82643407848195e+23*(-Tb2 + 1.12262552342427e-6*sqrt(Tb2**7))**7/Tb2**7
>>> nsolve(_, (270,300), solver='bisect', verify=False)
280.451434985005
```

Add this to your solution (and back substitute if you want numerical values for everything)

Add this to your solution (and back substitute if you want numerical values for everything)

```
>>> s3.update({Tb2:_})
>>> for k in reversed(s3):
...  for i in s3:
...    s3[i] = s3[i].subs(k,s3[k])
... 
>>> s3
{Va2: 22.661, Vb2: 47.3389, Ta2: 223.7519, pk: 246.2740, Tb2: 280.4514}
```

[numbers in solution were manually trimmed for display]